# Netbeans - delete auto generated Button Parameter

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

how can i delete the auto generated `java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt` in Netbeans when i double click in Swing on a Button?

Here is a sample from a auto generated Button-Click. How can i delete the unused parameter? Sadly the Codeline is grayed out in Netbeans.

```
private void sampleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

thanks in forward!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " How can i delete the unused parameter?"

The answer is, you **Don't** want it deleted. The parameter is **necessary**. Why? If you look in the uneditable auto-generated `initCompoents()`, you will see something like this

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        jButton1ActionPerformed(e);
    }
});
```

And the editable method they create for you is the

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
```

which requires the `ActionEvent` to be passed to it

Comment: Thanks for this Answer! But why the heck, SonarQube think, that this is a mistake?

Comment: @user3274436 Unfortunately I have no idea what SonarQube is. If you give me a link, maybe I can clarify what they are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this

[delete java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_events.html)

Comment: no, i just want to delete java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt, the parameter. Not the full block from the Button.

Comment: +1 for the link but it's better to include part of the answer here

Answer (score -1):

Go to Design and right click on button and select properties then click on Events and remove the unwanted one which you added wrongly.

[image: Remove event]

Comment: I just want to delete "java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt", not the whole block from the Button.

Comment: You cant. However consuming parameter is not necessary.